# Modelica array, how to correct the model Test

Tags: arrays, modelica

Why are the values of `a` and `a[1]` different? How do I have to correct the model Test?

```
model Test
    Real a[2](start={1,1});
    Real b(start=2);
equation
    der(a[2])=0;
    der(a[1])=b;
    der(b)=0;
    when a[1]>10 or a[1]<2 then
        reinit(b,-b);
    end when;
end Test;

model Test2
    Real a;
    Real b(start=2);
equation
    der(a)=b;
    der(b)=0;
    when a>10 or a<2 then
        reinit(b,-b);
    end when;
end Test2;
```

Comment: You're missing a start value for a? Real a(start = 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Because the initial values of `a[1]`=1 and `a`=0 are different.

Regards,
Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: thanks for replying.  But, that is not the answer supposing with the same initial value.     I have saved it,  the question caused by the tool of OpenModelica. I chosed another tool named

Comment: Wolfram SystemModeler Model Center